# Error comes in Expected expression?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

Here I tried to insert a value in `GLKVector2Add` value but the error comes expected expression missing in this line.

```
GLKVector2 self.position = GLKVector2Add({-200.695, 271},{-803.695, 0});  //Error - Expected expression
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating "`GLKVector2`" variables, setting them and then passing *those* as arguments in your call to "`GLKVector2Add`".  It may be that the compiler simply doesn't know what to do with "{-200.695,271}" (a mix of float and integer numbers).

Answer (score 0):

You must add them using `GLKVector2Make`.

So, your code will be:

```
GLKVector2 position = GLKVector2Add(
                      GLKVector2Make(-200.695, 271), 
                      GLKVector2Make(-803.695, 0));
```